# Filtering list view based on querystring using jQuery?

Tags: 2010, jquery, filter, spservices

Using Sharepoint 2010 
Content Editor Web Parts (some links dynamically created) 
List View Web Part

Ability to add additional software or packages to the system extremely limited (so would prefer answers that do not suggest software upgrades/additional different Web Parts)

Notes using javascript/JQuery and have access to SPServices.

Given the services I have access to, is there a way to filter the List View Web Part based on a querystring?

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the built-in filtering functionality of list view web parts - if you use the header dropdowns, they filter the list view by changing the url and adding parameters.

Most of the fields, however, are not very filter-friently. For example you cannot have multi-select on one column, and you cannot use regular expression to select all items starting with a given string. The built-in filtering works best when applied to choice/lookup fields (again, only single option is available).

Here is what Sharepoint adds as parameters:

```
AllItems.aspx?**View**={XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}&**FilterField1**=DocumentAuthor&**FilterValue1**=John%20Smith
```

You can remove the View parameter and value - it still works without them; the **FilterField1** defines the **static name** of the first field you want to filter by; **FilterValue1** defines the text string according to which your list will be filtered (using filterfield1).

You can filter by several fields. The fields must be visible in the view you are filtering by.

Comment: This seems to work when opening just the list.  The specific issue I inquired about was when the list is only shown in a list view web part.

Comment: This still works on my lists that are in list view web part - my LVWP has a header for filtering and it still adds filter parameters in the url. Perhaps it depends on the way you visualize your LVWP - you can try to insert it "as is" and it should show the header filters.